Convert table data into a ledger format using PostgreSQL query
I have the following data in a PostgreSQL table:



id
amount
opening_amount
closing_amount




1
200
1000
1200


2
-500
NULL
NULL


3
-200
NULL
NULL


4
1000
NULL
NULL



I want to convert this data into a ledger format, calculating the opening_amount and closing_amount based on the previous row's closing_amount and the amount.
The expected result is:



id
amount
opening_amount
closing_amount




1
200
1000
1200


2
-500
1200
700


3
-200
700
500


4
1000
500
1500



I tried using the LAG() function but it gives the wrong result:



id
amount
opening_amount
closing_amount




1
200
1000
1200


2
-500
1200
700


3
-200
1000
800


4
1000
1000
2000



Here is the query I tried:
WITH ledger_data AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        amount,
        COALESCE(LAG(closing_amount) OVER (ORDER BY id), 1000) AS opening_amount,  -- Assuming first record's opening balance is 1000
        amount + COALESCE(LAG(closing_amount) OVER (ORDER BY id), 1000) AS closing_amount
    FROM (VALUES
        (1, 200, 1000, 1200),
        (2, -500, NULL, NULL),
        (3, -200, NULL, NULL),
        (4, 1000, NULL, NULL)
    ) AS ledger(id, amount, opening_amount, closing_amount)
)
SELECT 
    id,
    amount,
    opening_amount,
    closing_amount
FROM ledger_data;

Issue: The LAG() function seems to be giving incorrect results for subsequent rows. I need to calculate the opening_amount and closing_amount in a cumulative way, where each row depends on the previous row's closing balance.
Can anyone suggest how I can fix this query to correctly generate the ledger format?

As you've found out, an analytic function can't include it's own result in a "subsequent" row. This is because SQL expressions must be able to be evaluated on any row independent of any other row. (SQL sets have no order, and so there's no "subsequent" row.)
You could use recursive CTEs to iterate over each row one at a time, but that would be cumbersome and (relatively) slow.
So, instead, keep a running total of each amount, and then do the maths.
WITH
  ledger_data (
    id, amount, opening_amount, closing_amount
  )
AS
(
  VALUES
    (1,  200, 1000, 1200),
    (2, -500, NULL, NULL),
    (3, -200, NULL, NULL),
    (4, 1000, NULL, NULL)
),
  running_total AS
(
  SELECT 
    id,
    amount,
    SUM(opening_amount)
      OVER (ORDER BY id)
        AS opening_amount,
    SUM(amount)
      OVER (ORDER BY id)
        AS cumulative_amount 
  FROM
      ledger_data
)
SELECT
  id,
  amount,
  opening_amount + cumulative_amount - amount   AS opening_amount,
  opening_amount + cumulative_amount            AS closing_amount
FROM
  running_total
ORDER BY
  id
;




id
amount
opening_amount
closing_amount




1
200
1000
1200


2
-500
1200
700


3
-200
700
500


4
1000
500
1500




SELECT 4


fiddle

One option is to self join your table data with previous row and calculate what you need using analytic function Sum() Over() with the windowing clause ...
--      S Q L :  
Select     t.id, t.amount, 
           Sum(Coalesce(t.opening_amount, 0) + Coalesce(t1.amount, 0)) Over( Order By t.id 
                   Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row ) as opening_amount,
           Sum(Coalesce(t.opening_amount, 0) + t.amount) Over( Order By t.id 
                   Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row ) as closing_amount
From       tbl t
Left Join  tbl t1 ON(t1.id = t.id - 1)

R e s u l t :



id
amount
opening_amount
closing_amount




1
200.00
1000.00
1200.00


2
-500.00
1200.00
700.00


3
-200.00
700.00
500.00


4
1000.00
500.00
1500.00



fiddle
